# Detect Google Chrome Live Captioning

Tags: google-chrome, closed-captions

Google has released a new accessibility feature in Chrome 89 called [Live Captions](https://blog.google/products/chrome/live-caption-chrome/). This is a great feature, except in our exact use case. Our site is used by schools and education, where teachers and students can provide feedback on videos. Some schools use our site for teaching languages. Specially where they have to watch a video and type what they hear.

The problem comes in with Live Captions where the student can cheat on tests by enabling Live Captions and just type what they see. We have our own CC button that we can let the teacher disable for tests, but if the browser has native CC, then the point is moot.

While temporarily disabling Live Captions would be ideal, if we could even detect that it was enabled we could tell the user to turn it off before starting the test. Is this possible?